# Lazily Transforming IReadOnlyList in C#

Tags: c#, list

I would like to be able to do something like this for setting up a
mesh data structure.

```
IReadOnlyList<Point> points;
IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<int>> triangles;
```

where the triangles are indices into the points list. Given an index
of a triangle ''ti'' we can find the points easily

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = triangles[ti].Select(pi=>points[pi])
```

However I would like to be able to define a convienience structure

```
IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<Point>> trianglesAsPoints;
```

so I can do

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = triangles[ti]
```

The obvious way to do this would be to create a linq like selector

```
IReadOnlyList<T> Select( this IReadOnlyList<U> This
                             , Func<U,T> selector)
```

which returns an instance whose class overrides the following method and
invokes the selector

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the element at the specified index in the read-only list.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   index:
    //     The zero-based index of the element to get.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The element at the specified index in the read-only list.
    T this[int index] { get; }
}
```

Does such a factory exist anywhere in the standard libs or nuget for this pattern?
Note I do not want IEnumerable as a result because I would lose the indexing ability
and the Count property, I just want to lazily transform the value which means **not**
copying all the values to a new list instance up front.

Answer (score 3):

I don't *believe* there's anything which does this in the framework, no. It's obviously reasonably easy to implement yourself, but I believe you'll have to do it. It's entirely possible that there are 3rd party libraries which do it, but as `IReadOnlyCollection` was only in .NET 4.5 it's less likely than if the interface had existed for a while.

I'd suggest calling it something other than `Select` though - I'd use `ProjectView` or something similar. Of course that means it wouldn't work with LINQ query expressions, but it will be clearer to anyone reading the code that it's *not* just `Enumerable.Select`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hand rolled solution to the problem

```
public static class CollectionMixins
{
    private class ReadOnlyListProjection<U,T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
    {

        public Func<U,T> Selector { get; private set; }
        public IList<U> List { get; private set; }

        public ReadOnlyListProjection(IList<U> list, Func<U, T> selector)
        {
            List = list;
            Selector = selector;
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return Selector(List[index]);  }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return List.Count; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return List.Select(Selector).GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return List.Select(Selector).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<T> ProjectReadOnly<U, T>(this IList<U> This, Func<U, T> fn)
    {
        return new ReadOnlyListProjection<U, T>(This, fn);
    }
}
```

so I can now do

```
IList<int> foo = new List<int>{0,1,2};
IReadOnlyList<string> bar = foo.ProjectReadOnly( x=>x.ToString() );
```